# Copy and Paste only working on second attempt

Tags: 19.04, copy, paste

just wondering if anybody else is experiencing a weird issue I am able to replicate across multiple machines running Ubuntu 19.04

I have updated all machines to the latest repo packages, and this issue has only just recently started since upgrading so I am thinking it might be a recent update that has been pushed.

But it seems Copy And Paste, either using CTRL + C + V or even via right mouse click action  appears not to work on the first attempt

it seems to regularly happen for me.  I'm a Developer, Blogger, Document Writer so regularly have to copy and paste text while editing etc.

So I have identified this issue starting early this week,  I think I updated and upgraded all packages this week - 22 July 2019.  So I am assuming it might be related to an update.

I want to confirm if anybody else has noticed before I raise an issue.

Comment: Can you narrow this down a bit: within which program are you trying to copy the text (browser, terminal, email program, word processor - and which one). How are you doing the selection of the text (double click with with mouse, drag and select with mouse...?). And where are you trying to paste the text that (presumably) doesn't show up - into the same program, into another program? What happens when you try and paste - nothing shows up? Text selected from the last time you copied text? Something unrelated/unexpected?

Comment: might be a workaround but it also might be affected by your problem. I use parcellite as my text clipboard manager.   sudo apt install parcellite    ctrl-alt-h is it's hotkey. it saves a history of copied text items for reuse.

Comment: I confirm this issue (Ubuntu 19.10), though it only happens in virtual machine (KVM). The host (also 19.10) works fine.

Comment: I can confirm this issue as well. Ubuntu 19.10. Unable to narrow it down, sometimes it works on the first time - sometimes it won't.

Comment: A simple solution will be to disable clipboard on virt-manager and only enable it when needed: https://askubuntu.com/a/1363086/311094